# After I getting a set-cookie in response, is not saved and transmitted in requests

Tags: node.js, cookies, setcookie, fastify

Basically after an auth, I setting a cookie, but apparently after page refresh on the cookie that was set by cloudflare is saved
And the cookie that I transmitted with set-cookie is not used in after set-cookie requests

```sh
# Response headers
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Thu, 18 Jul 2019 10:03:25 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 29
set-cookie: __cfduid=d578c7a5e4378dc1b1946964a08ebc4ec1563444205; expires=Fri, 17-Jul-20 10:03:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.doc.io; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie: __doc=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlIjoiNzQ2NTczNzQ0MDY2NjE3Mzc0NmQ2MTY5NmMyZTZkNzgiLCJwIjoiNTUzMjQ2NzM2NDQ3NTY2YjU4MzEzODMzNTU0NjUwNTU2ZjRiMzkzMTY3NDUzNDY5NDc3MzM3MzgzOTU5MzczMDUxNjk0ZjQxNjQ0OTM5Nzg0YjZiNzU1Njc3Nzk0NDc0NjE3NDMxNTE0NzcwMzE0YjQxNmY1MjU5MzM3YTZhNDU2NDJiNmU0ZTc0NGE3NTMyNTQ1ODc2NjI1YTczNDc1MTQ1Njc0MjVhNGQ0MTNkM2QiLCJkIjoiMzEzNTM2MzMzNDM0MzQzMjMwMzUzNTM2MzMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjM0NDQyMDV9.go1jDpc2rBe5FjK2sKX4ybW4PhCPFq1xT1WIX-mSI84; Domain=.doc.io; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 18 Jul 2019 16:03:25 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 4f83a02a3dc36455-FRA
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

```js
reply
.code(200)
.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.setCookie('__doc', token, {
domain: '.doc.io',
path: '/',
secure: true,
httpOnly: true,
expires: new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 6))})
.send({ 'success': 'Sign In success' })
```

All my websites are https

First I do POST request for an auth on `/auth`, and you could see response in response headers above and after I do GET on (trying to load page) from `/page` and get cookies, but with `reply.log.info(request.cookies)` I see only cookies from cloudflare. Surely I tried to refresh and go to address in different table, there just no any cookies, but from cloudflare.

```sh
# Request headers
Host: test.doc.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __cfduid=d578c7a5e4378dc1b1946964a08ebc4ec1563444205
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
TE: Trailers
```

Comment: I removed httpOnly: true as it seems shouldn't work for json request types, however changes nothing

Comment: Now I'm, really confused as it seems it works in Chromium, but not works in Firefox even with new clear profile

Answer (score 0):

After I tested it with an actual page with js code for a XHR request it works fine. However cookie was only displayed, but not actually saved in the storage when I was sending request directly in Firefox's inspector. Lost a day to figure out that created in inspector cookies seems preventing from installing